# "0" In Key makes the code Sort incorrectly Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sorting, object

Sorting by key doesn't work if it has "0"

```
const resObj = { '15': 686, '03': 598, '14': 803, '16': 1000, "04": 123 };
const resData = Object.entries(resObj).sort(([a,], [b,]) => a - b)
                      .reduce((o, [k, v]) => ({...o, [k]: v}), {})
```

output:

```
{ '14': 803, '15': 686, '16': 1000, '03': 598, '04': 123 }
```

And when "0" is not in the key, it will work

```
const resObj = { '15': 686, '13': 598, '14': 803, '16': 1000, '17': 123 };
```

output:

```
{ '13': 598, '14': 803, '15': 686, '16': 1000, '17': 123 }
```

Could someone please explain why it become that way

Comment: At least in client-side JS in the browser, this does not appear to reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/526cvte7/ (tested in Chromium-based browser)

Comment: @CBroe it will be reproducible if you loop through keys of the object.

Comment: You can't sort the keys of the object keys with integer indices (A number which looks like an array index). `03` is considered as a non-numerical key.

Comment: const resObj = [{ '15': 686, '03': 598, '14': 803, '16': 1000, "04": 123 }];

function CompareKey(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}


resObj.sort(CompareKey);

console.log(resObj);

Comment: Moreover, if the keys are correct representations of integers (unsigned 32 bit range), they are already sorted. No need to call sort. You cannot change that sort order anyway.